# Doctrine count records of table

Tags: doctrine, symfony

I would like to know how I can count all records of an entity in a doctrine repository

I found this solution but am not sure if this is good so:

```php
public function findAllCounted()
{
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery('SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM KSRArticleBundle:Article a')
        ->getSingleScalarResult();
}
```

Best Regards,
Bodo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need to count on a specific field, so this will do:

```
SELECT COUNT(a) FROM KSRArticleBundle:Article a
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for the record, it is usually better to count on the id :

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM KSRArticleBundle:Article a
```

is a little better

Comment: Because MySql does not have to list all informations on the lines, he just counts the ids. It is better in MyISAM, I do not know if it still stands on InnoDB though.

Comment: +1 for counting the .id - @Chausser Because the ID is indexed, so the query only counts the index instead of all data rows...

Answer (score 0):

SQL also allows this:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM KSRArticleBundle:Article a
```

In this way the database does not even have to fetch any data from the table, which is even faster. Literally what it says: select the number of the constant '1' for every record. Small speed increase for well-designed data base servers and you dont have to remember anything about the table when writing this.

Answer (score 0):

the result of the query is an array which always has a position zero and a parameter "1"

```
$recordnumber= $number[0]["1"];
```

the table name should be equal to the entity name and start with a capital